# How do I stop Excel 2013 from updating external links?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a 2013 Excel document with external links to other documents.

The problem is that the documents referenced in the cells are not available on my network.

Excel still updates the value of those cells depite me telling him not to in the prompt.

I have tried to disable all external access in the trust center with no luck.

How do I stop Excel from auto-updating those cells ?

Answer (score 0):

To stop cells from automatically updating, [copy them as values instead of linked cells](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Copy-cell-values-not-formulas-12687b4d-c79f-4137-b0cc-947c229c55b9). If you right click when pasting, you should see other options from just "paste". One of them is an icon which looks like a clipboard with numbers in the bottom left corner. It's called "Paste Values" and will paste only the values.

note - this is for the latest version of Excel. From memory, 2013 has a similar layout and the same option available.

Comment: Thanks but the values get updated even before I have a chance to copy them.

Comment: I mean when initially creating the spread sheet. It may be worth creating a copy of the spread sheet on the network where the documents are available, editing it so it's just values and internal formulae, and going from there.

Comment: I was hoping to find the Excel 2010 behaviour which allows me to open the file without updating the values. Editing the file is impossible as I don't have the external links.

Comment: Sorry, but I've not encountered the behaviour you're describing, so I'm afraid I'm limited to providing alternate solutions! Is there a way the original author/provider of the spreadsheet could send you a copy that's just values?

Comment: Yeah I could ask but I was hoping there was another way !